# Spring Roo Multi Project Workaround

Tags: spring-roo

I know Spring Roo doesn't support multi project yet, but I need two sites to run on the same models / controllers (about 50 models) and on the same database without having to update models on both applications.

I was thinking that I could generate the models and controllers in a master project and have the child projects use symlinked models and controllers. This still feels like I'm duplicating a lot of code, is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking into having a UI customization for different clients for the same product built using Spring Roo, you can simply achieve the above with the use of a Version Control System.

Just fork your main source for two branches and keep updating the trunk and pull them to the branches when there is a change to the modules, while maintaining the individual UI customizations in the branches.

Additionally, you can wait for Spring Roo 1.2 release which has already promised multi-module maven project support ([ROO-120](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-120)) for Spring Roo projects.

Cheers and all the best with Roo!

Comment: The version control is a very elegant solution, thanks!
Wish I had the time to wait around for 1.2 RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround I'm trying to create separate Roo web projects for different business logics. Then I modify the packaging in the pom.xml, from WAR to JAR in order to package them without web resources (note: since the controllers are POJO classes, they are included in the JAR)

I call them helper modules.

Finally, I create a Roo web project importing the helper modules as maven dependencies.

I call it the main module.

The first issue is to include the classes of the helper modules in the JPA scanning of the main module. I need to do this because the top level packages are different among the modules.

In order to achieve that, you need to edit the persistence.xml within the main module and add  entries for each foreign JPA entity (yepes, 50 if necessary)

See: http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46259&tstart=0 for further explanations.

The second issue is to use the Controllers included in the JARs. The problem here is the ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean, you'll need to copy the code of each ApplicationConversionServiceFactoryBean within the helper modules in the main module, since the webmvc-config.xml only creates one of it.

It's a issue only if you have entities with composite keys, because they are @Autowired in the Controllers in order to make conversations of the keys for using them as REST parameters.

See http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46337&tstart=0 for further details.

The last issue could be the JSON Aspects created for the exchange of the REST parameters in the AJAX calls, as above, if you have composite keys. Furthermore, if you're trying to use JQuery instead of Dojo.

I don't have a solution for that yet, but the end of the project is near, so I'm sure that something will come to help.

By the way, I accept suggestions.

Comment: Also a good solution, if I had the time to do it properly, this would probably be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There might be another way to accomplish it, using Spring resolvers... If interested you can review my article on the matter at http://pragmatikroo.blogspot.com/2011/04/spring-roodynamic-clients-multiple.html.

This approach is particular useful on web sites with traditional UI clients that need to support mobile client at the same time.

I hope it helps.

B. Roogards
jD